# Detecting PHP binary path - strange situation

Tags: php, binary, centos, virtualmin

I have no PHP_BINARY nor PHP_BINDIR in my phpinfo output. There's 3 versions on the server - 5.3 5.6 7.0 and Virtualmin. Default is 5.6 - it servers http requests fine. But I also need to run cronjobs by this version, but

```
# /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2017 12:27:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Another attempt:

```
whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /etc/php.ini /etc/php.d /usr/lib64/php /usr/share/php 
/usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

Here is my phpinfo's text.
https://pastebin.com/T0WSwJ1c

Please help!

Added - I changed php mode from fastcgi to Apache handler, and again - no PHP_BINARY nor PHP_BINDIR in 5.6 phpinfo output. I searched for all php-like files

```
find / -name 'php*' > php.txt
```

result is here
https://justpaste.it/1bwap

and I found cgi binary(?) `/home/***/cgi-bin/php5.6.cgi` (username sensored)
ok it return 5.6 version but how to run cron with this?!

```
# /home/****/cgi-bin/php5.6.cgi ./t.php
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Filename cannot be empty in Unknown on line 0
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.25
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No input file specified.
```

Comment: one of the other ones you found is probably correct. Just replace the one in /usr/bin/php with the correct one

Comment: /usr/bin/php5.6 -v
/usr/bin/php56 -v
not found

Comment: what the `ls /usr/share/php`  shows? Also how about a `locate php` command too?

Comment: first is empty output, `locate` not found, `yum install locate `- no package available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly I found it at `/opt/rh/rh-php56/root/usr/bin/php`

When I posted `find / -name 'php*' > php.txt` I removed a bunch of /opt/rh/something.. results thinking of them as quite irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Well in GNU+Linux systems and similar (eg. Freebsd) you can find all the executables either in `/bin` or in `/usr/bin` therefore the `php` command is the `/usr/bin/php`.

Also in order to mimilize the results you can use the `-b` option into the `whereis` command in order to find the php executable.

A good way to find out is to execute via a shell:

```bash
/usr/bin/php -v
```

Comment: /usr/bin/php -v prints PHP 5.3.3 version but apache use 5.6 and I search for the last one.